# VueJS Multiselect behavior

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vue-component

I am struggling to make the vue-multiselect work the way I intend. I have a few things I'd like to accomplish:

1. Close on selected value. I have it setup so that only one value can be selected. But I have to now select and then click away to close it. Any ideas how to achieve this?
2. When searching and then selecting, the search text stays in the field and overlaps with the selected value. Obviously this is not desired.
3. The multiselect appears by default bellow the input field, if there is not enough space, it appears above. The problem is that when displaying above, it appears over the input field. Is there any way to fix or to force display bellow the input field always?

Thanks so much for any input on this.

Comment: You need to add some code to your question, and ideally a snippet where we can see the problem in a running example.